# How to randomly select a defined number elements from sets proportional to another set?

Tags: algorithm, random

## Introduction

Let `S1 = {e11, e12, e13,...,e1n}` `S2={e21, e22, e23,...,e2i}` ,`S3={e31, e32, e33,...,e3j}`, `S4 ={e41, e42, e43,...,e4k}` be sets of **float** elements of dimensions `n, i, j` and `k`.

For set `S1` we want to select a random subset of elements **E** from `S2`, `S3` and `S4`. The dimension of the subset should be equal to `10 x |S1|`.

---

## Problem

Since I am **randomly** selecting a subset of elements from `S2`, `S3` and `S4`. There is a possibility or a probability that all the elements of the subset be selected from just `S4` **or** from just `S2` and `S3` **or** from  just `S2`.

What formula can we use in order to satisfy the following constraints:

- The Elements of the subset are selected from `S2`, `S3` and `S4`
- The dimension of the subset is equal to **10 x dimension of S1**
- We pick at least **1** element from each set

We must also take into account that the sets have different dimensions.

---

### Example

```
S1 = {1.0, 2.0}
S2 = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}
S3 = {7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 30.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0, 600.0}
S4 = {10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0}
```

The size of the random subset is `10 x |S1| = 20`. We must randomly select `20` elements from `S2, S3` and `S4`.

---

## Union

```
S2 ∪ S3 ∪ S4 = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 30.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0}

|S2 ∪ S3 ∪ S4| = 30
```

If we randomly select **20** elements from `|S2 ∪ S3 ∪ S4|` we might have a chance of **not** selecting `{4.0, 5.0, 6.0}`.

Comment: You need to pick at least one element from each set?

Comment: Yes @TamasIonut. sorry I didn't explain correctly. excuse me i'll add it

Comment: Select one element from each set first, and then create the union (without the selected elements) and select the additional elements? That would guarantee at least one from each set.

Comment: Exactly as @m69 said, are there any other requirements? Otherwise, you could select those elements randomly and use the below algo.

Comment: There's no way to do it completely random, you need to throw in some kind of non-randomness somewhere. Like in the suggestion by @m69 to do an initial round-robin selection.

Comment: sheesh I feel already stupid. That's it .  @m69

Comment: @HaniGoc precise random generators are way off budget. So relying on Random is pretty good for your purposes.

Comment: @HaniGoc We all overlook the obvious sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
        Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        HashSet<float> set1 = new HashSet<float>(...);
        HashSet<float> set2 = new HashSet<float>(...);
        HashSet<float> set3 = new HashSet<float>(...);
        HashSet<float> set4 = new HashSet<float>(...);

        set2.UnionWith(set3);
        set2.UnionWith(set4);

        IEnumerable<float> resultSet = set2.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).Take(set1.Count*10);
```

Comment: So the *algorithm* is to create a union of the three sets, and randomly select the correct number of elements from the union?

Comment: No other constraints or requirements were specified.

Comment: @TamasIonut and will that guarantee that we select elements from S2,S3 and S4?

Comment: Pretty much. Unless UnionWith API is flawed, but that is unlikely.

Comment: But is not guaranteed to get distinct elements from s2/3/4. So basically, you can get duplicates from these sets.

Comment: Please don't use capital letters. This provided solution will select elements from s2, s3 or s4 randomly. What kind of guarantees do you need and what kind of sorting are you referring to?

Comment: Actually with this algorithm there is no guarantee that the items selected will be from all three sets. Random being random means that this algorithm might pick elements from only two, or even just one of the sets. That elements from all three sets are in the union doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I didn't explain well Sorry. I had to add **At least one element from each set**